# cpp file is being saved in wrong format and was unable to solve it

Tags: c++, file, notepad++

my notepad++ cpp is file shows an internet explorer sign as it is being saved, opens in internet explorer or I have not choose which software I want to use to open it, instead of just opening in notepadd++, but when ever I try to see the info about file it shows cpp I looked up and didn't find any such question to get answer from.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/18539/windows-7-change-default-programs

Comment: Your `cpp` file has been associated with `IE` and what you want to do is to associate it with `notepad++`. The way of doing this depends on version of `Windows` you are using. You should add windows version to your question in order for others to be able to provide you with meaningful solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's being saved with the wrong ending. are you hiding file extensions in explorer? Right click on the file and check the name in properties. Also you want to ensure that file extensions are always shown. Go into "view" in Windows Explorer and ensure that "file extensions" checkbox is on (later Windows versions). Or in earlier Windows/Windows in general, click into Folder Options/View and turn **off** "Hide Extensions for known files". As a developer you always want file extensions shown.

If you have the wrote file extension and it's hidden the file could be like "file.cpp.txt" or "file.cpp.html" or something instead of an actual cpp file.

Once you've double-checked the file extension and made sure file extensions are not hidden, if that isn't it, right click the desired file and look at "Open With", "Choose Another App/Program" (depending on Windows version), then look for the right program to open it with and make sure you click "always open with this program".

Comment: hi thanks for the info, no I can not see the extension and I did not hide it intentionally; I tried to go to the file property and could not find any way to fix the situation, if I right click I see cpp file but probably as you said this might cpp.html . what's windows explorer, how do I access it? thanks again :)

Comment: hi I was able to make file extension visible , they are all being saved as cpp file but still with internet explorer icon and open in internet explorer or I have to choose the what I want to use to open my code :/

Comment: right click the file, choose "open with ..." from the menu, then pick another program, and make sure to click "always open with" or whatever it's labeled as. all files with that extension will then be associated with what you picked.

Comment: yuh that's what I am being asked to do, but I am not being given notepad++ as one of my options to open with, thanks :)

Comment: look in more apps, then browse, and navigate manually to where the notepad++ exe file is, then select that. you can do it manually.